# Clone an element on document.ready, only stored in variable for first action

Tags: jquery

I am trying to clone a div and store it in a variable on page load, and then append it everytime that a button is clicked. But it only works when I click the button for the first time. Any idea why that is?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var inquiryItem;
  inquiryItem = $('.firstItem').clone();

  $('body').on('click', '.create-inquiry-add', function() {
    $(inquiryItem).addClass('animated fadeIn newitem').removeClass('firstItem').insertAfter('.inquiry-item:last-child');
  });
});
```

Comment: Do you want the end result to have multiple divs inserted at different points in the DOM, or just one div that moves around?

Answer (score 0):

You are cloning it only once so using `append()` method will just move same element (to same place i guess). Your code should be:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $inquiryItem = $('.firstItem');
    $('body').on('click', '.create-inquiry-add', function () {
        $inquiryItem.clone().toggleClass('animated fadeIn newitem firstItem').insertAfter('.inquiry-item:last-child');
    });
});
```

Using `toggleClass()` for simplicity if former element hasn't `animated fadeIn newitem` classes set by default.